# Django dynamically changing the required property on forms

Tags: django, forms, dynamic

I want to dynamically change the required attribute on form fields. The reason for doing this is because a user can select "Same address as previous user" yes/no.

If yes then it hides the fields on the frontend and I would want to make the fields which are required by default not required when validating / processing the modelform.

Comment: I've tried solution 1. given in Noah's answer

Comment: The question sounds reasonably clear to me. Maybe the language/punctuation can be improved but the question doesn't seem unclear.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a very nice discussion of this topic in general: [Dynamic form requirements in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229427/dynamic-form-requirements-in-django?rq=1) .

If you just want to do something really simple, there are two very basic ways that I can think of:

1. Set the field to not be required and use a custom clean function to check that it exists when it should exist. (If you want an asterisk to appear after the field title, just use some simple javascript.)
2. Have two different forms--one with the field required and one without--and use javascript to display the correct form.

The first solution is obviously much simpler for exactly what you asked, but if you want to do something even slightly more complicated, you might prefer the second option.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I have tried 1. But I didnt want to add the asterisk with JS as it seemed more of a work around.. and not integrated nicely with the current logic..

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10967900/1526703) explains option 1 above with code.